# Problem with installing Ubuntu 13.04 alongside with windows 8

Tags: installation, usb, windows-8

I have tried the written tip but it doesn't work so any idea how to solve this? By the way this happened with my only with windows 8. This is Ubuntu installation from USB flash memory,

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Nope, that solution won't work with me because Ubuntu is not even installed i am trying to install it this message appears directly after choosing Try Ubuntu before installing.

Comment: I myself have no idea of how to solve it **But** if your Windows 8 is Pre-installed and 64 bits this might help: [Check the first answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Comment: Its not because i have tried it on my another computer and it just works fine its start up with no problems.